# Access value of colframe in custom drawing for tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, pgfkeys

I am trying to make a `tcolorbox` that uses custom code to draw its frame but which accesses the color stored in `colframe`.

So far I have tried

```
\newtcolorbox{leftborderbox}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colframe=orange,
    colback=orange!20,
    frame code={
        \fill[fill=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/colframe}] (frame.south west) -- (interior.south west) -- (interior.north west) -- (frame.north west);
        },
    sharp corners,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=5pt,
    right=5pt,
    top=6pt,
    bottom=6pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    leftrule=4pt,
    #1
}

\begin{leftborderbox}[colframe=pink]
    Hi There!
\end{leftborderbox}
```

but I get an error about `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tcb/colframe}` not being a color.  How do I access the value of this key?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490074/tcolorbox-tcbcolback-and-tcbcolframe-are-undefined-in-4-20/490097#490097 for the official color names (from version 4.20)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the colours being specified to the `tcolorbox` options are available with a prefix `tcbcol@`, e.g.

- `tcbcol@frame` for the colour of the frame
- `tcbcol@title` -- title text colour
- `tcbcol@back` -- background colour
- `tcbcol@upper` -- upper box text colour
- `tcbcol@lower` -- lower box text colour
- `tcbcol@backtitle` -- background colour of title

In the default `\tcbset` setting in `tcolorbox.sty` those `tcbcol@...` are actually statements for `.colorlet:`

```
\tcbset{... % excerpt from tcolorbox.sty

  colback/.colorlet=tcbcol@back,
  colframe/.colorlet=tcbcol@frame,
  colupper/.colorlet=tcbcol@upper,
  collower/.colorlet=tcbcol@lower,
  coltext/.style={colupper=#1,collower=#1},
  coltitle/.colorlet=tcbcol@title,
...
}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{leftborderbox}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colframe=orange,
    colback=orange!20,
    frame code={
      \fill[fill=tcbcol@frame] (frame.south west) -- (interior.south west) -- (interior.north west) -- (frame.north west);
      \draw (0,0) node {};
    },
    sharp corners,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=5pt,
    right=5pt,
    top=6pt,
    bottom=6pt,
    boxrule=0pt,
    leftrule=4pt,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{leftborderbox}[colframe=pink]
    Hi There!
\end{leftborderbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Is there any way to access the `.colorlet` attribute so I don't need to dig into the internals of `tcolorbox`?

Comment: @JasonSiefken: You're welcome. Sometimes, it's necessary to look into package codes to get the relevant information. I had to so recently quite a lot concerning the colour settings of `tcolorbox`, so I remembered this

Comment: @JasonSiefken: I know of no such way but this doesn't mean there's none

Comment: For anyone using version 4.20, please refer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490097/167081).