# Tcolorbox tcbcol@back and tcbcol@frame are undefined in 4.20

Tags: errors, tcolorbox

Tcolorbox `tcbcol@back` and `tcbcol@frame` are undefined in new version (4.20) of package. What one should to use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375181/121799) and comparing this to the updated version of `tcolorbox.sty` in which you can find

```
...
colback/.colorlet=tcbcolback,
colframe/.colorlet=tcbcolframe,
....
```

suggests that you need to use `tcbcolback` and `tcbcolframe` instead.

Answer (score 7):

The internal color names became *official* with version 4.20. Therefore, the `@` was removed from the old names.

Here are the offical names (from the documentation):

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to define `tcolframe` if `tcol@frame` exists to preserve compatibility with multiple tcolorbox versions?

Comment: @JasonSiefken To patch an old version (2018 or older), you could do something like `\tcbset{colframe/.code={\colorlet{tcbcolframe}{#1}\colorlet{tcbcol@frame}{#1}}}` to set both color names.